# SOMA calls or datapower installed via docker

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have installed Datapower on my personal laptop through docker.
But I am unable to make calls to DataPower using soap UI.
 I am getting an error in soap ui as - connection to the ip:port reused

Do I need to do any additional setup?

My DP IP - https://localhost:9090

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open and forward ports between your localhost and the Docker container and of course also start SOMA in the Docker DataPower instance.

```
docker run -it -v D:/Docker/idg01/config:/drouter/config -v D:/Docker/idg01/local:/drouter/local -e DATAPOWER_ACCEPT_LICENSE=true -e DATAPOWER_INTERACTIVE=true -p 9090:9090 -p 5550:5550 -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 8084:8084 -p 8085:8085  --name idg01 ibmcom/datapower
```

I run the above to start mine which opens the ports 5550 (for SOMA) and 8080-8085 for services, e.g. HTTP front-side-handlers.

And check that SOMA is running under Administration on port 5550!

Comment: Does DataPower has docker image publicly available?

Comment: Yes, on Docker hub!

Answer (score 0):

I am using below config I use 8000-8010 port for services and 9022 Port for SSH and 9090 for Web-Mgmt .
docker run -it 
-v $PWD/config:/drouter/config 
-v $PWD/local:/drouter/local 
-e DATAPOWER_ACCEPT_LICENSE=true 
-e DATAPOWER_INTERACTIVE=true 
-p 9090:9090 
-p 9022:22 
-p 5554:5554 
-p 8000-8010:8000-8010 
--name idg 
ibmcom/datapower